# Notepad++ regex, replacing unique values with unique values

Tags: json, notepad++

I have JSON which contains lots of data among others it contains multiple ID's. Each ID contains both numbers and letters. Each ID is unique.

- Example how it looks:    `"Id": "3L2kVk023"`
- How I want it to look (number may be random): `"Id": "156228427"`

My application doesn't longer accept ID with letter so I need to change all of them into numbers, and each ID must be unique.

Is there any automatic way to do it in Notepad++? I find it difficult to write regex for it since all ID's are unique and must be replaced one by one.

Comment: You could define your seach regex as `"Id": "[a-z0-9]+"`. And replace value as `"Id": "..."`. But that will still leave you with the problem, what to do at `...` because you would need some random generator and furthermore check for uniqueness. So unless there is some notepad++ plugin for that I'd say: No this is not possible with notepad++ regular expressions, but you need to write a script for that

Comment: any tips how this script could look? Something I could read?

Comment: Hard to say without further information. How does the file look like, what languages are you familiar with, ... If you say it's JSON, the way to go is object manipulation on the JSON data instead of string manipulation with regex ...

Comment: python, I will try to read about how to manipulate this data. I think the biggest struggle will be to replace all specifik ID with random number. Because each ID even if it is unique can be used more than 1 time but I hope I will figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with normal regular-expression replacement in Notepad++. The best way to do it in Notepad++ is with the PythonScript plugin.

If it is not yet installed, follow this link: [Guide: How to install the PythonScript plugin on Notepad++](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

Create a script from Notepad++ main menu (**Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script**) using the code below and save the file (e.g. `replace-random.py`)

```
import re
import random
import hashlib

def calculate(match):
    # copy match (only for better understanding)
    IdFound = match.group(0)
    # make sure passing an encoded string
    IdNew = int(hashlib.sha256(IdFound.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), 16) % 10**9
    # format return string
    return '"Id": "' + str(IdNew) + '",'

editor.rereplace(r'"Id": "[A-Za-z0-9]+",', calculate)
```

Let's assume the following JSON records are to be processed (note: the first and last ID are the same).

```json
{
    "Order ID": 4984,
    "Parts group": "INTERIO",
    "Id": "3K2kVk023",
    "Order description": "justo. Nullam"
},
{
    "Order ID": 1925,
    "Parts group": "ELECTRA",
    "Id": "3L2kWk024",
    "Order description": "imperdiet"
},
{
    "Order ID": 8651,
    "Parts group": "INTERIO",
    "Id": "3K2kVk023",
    "Order description": "eu pede mollis"
}
```

- Open the file you want to edit in Notepad++.
- Run the script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> replace-random)

This is resulting in:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't protect you from duplicate ID's.

Comment: That is so helpful of you! I appreciate your help. Actually it is very good that it fullfills duplicates. I am wondering if you maybe know if we can somehow add to this script to check value "Summary"? My file contains items ID's and if there is some sub items we give there ID of parent item which is ID. So if some ID is summary for other items it must be changed together.

Comment: Rather than using random numbers for the IDs, it may be suitable to use a simple increasing number. Perhaps starting at "100000000" to match the number of digits in the question.